# Appbar focuses included searchbar on appearance

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm developing a Windows Store App and have a AppBottom-Bar with an Searchbox and other controls.

When I run the app on a touch device and let the AppBar appear - the Seachbox automatically gets focused and the virtual keyboard appears. How do I prevent this behavior and only let the keyboard showing if the user clicks on the Searchbox?

Comment: You can set focus to other control, which can get focus and needn't input with keyboard.

Comment: I tried to set the focus to the appbar without success. But it would be better to prevent the searchbar being focused.